# Edit data during SQL Query without editing table before hand

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am running a query from access 2015 (I don't have a choice here) and am getting the following output.

```
course_id       long_name                         short_name    Class Descriptor    status
0AGR1A          10 AGRICULTURE                        10 AG                          active
0ENG1A          YEAR 10 ENGLISH                       10 ENG                         active
0HPE1A          10 HEALTH & PERSONAL DEVELOPMENT      10 HPE                         active
0SCI1A          10 SCIENCE                            10 SCIENCE                     active
0SCO1A          SAASTA                                                               active
```

I need to add _2020 to the end of every cell in the course_id column. So they will be 0AGR1A_2020 and so on.

I am using the following query to get this data

```
SELECT SCHOOCD.[Class Number] AS course_id, SCHOOSUB.[Subject Name] AS long_name, SCHOOSUB.[Subject Short Name] AS short_name, SCHOOCDE.[Class Descriptor], "active" AS status
FROM (SCHOOCD INNER JOIN SCHOOSUB ON SCHOOCD.[Subject Code] = SCHOOSUB.[Subject Code]) LEFT JOIN SCHOOCDE ON SCHOOCD.[Class Number] = SCHOOCDE.[Class Number]
WHERE (((SCHOOSUB.[Subject Name])<>"UNAVAILABLE") AND ((SCHOOCD.[Academic Period])=0 Or (SCHOOCD.[Academic Period])=5 Or (SCHOOCD.[Academic Period])=1));
```

I gather I need to do something like

```
UPDATE SCHOOCD SET course_id = CONCAT(course_id, '_2020')
```

But I cant get it working. I'm super new to SQL so anu suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems a little ambiguous. You want to change the data in the table or just in the output of the query without touching the table's contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `concat()` function in Access. You can use `&` instead:

```
course_id & "_2020"
```

If you want this in your `select` statement:

```
SELECT SCHOOCD.[Class Number] & "_2020" AS course_id, ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

If you are looking for an `update`, that permanently modifies the values in the table:

```
UPDATE SCHOOCD SET [Class Number] = [Class Number] & "_2020"
```

Comment: You are an absolute lifesaver. Thank you!